While trying to recover lost data from defunct account
I'm trying to recover lost data and was sent a code to scan but received this message??
{"success":false,"message":"[NumberFormatException]For input string:"null:""}}
Is there a simple solution for a non-programmer to proceed? Thank you for any help or advice you can give me.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
